# UIButton tap area is shifting after flipping superview

Tags: ios, swift

I am using an animated flipping of cardView with a button as it's subview along with other views. Animation, as well as images/texts, is displayed correctly in simulator/device/debugger.

The problem is with tap area - after flipping button tap is recognized in opposite corner. Can anyone suggest why am I having this issue? Thanks!

Code for animation is posted below, button constraints are checked with the debugger and they are correct.

```
fileprivate func flippingHandler(forView view: UIView) {
    guard let cardContentView = view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is CardContentView} ) as? CardContentView,
        let initialCardView = cardContentView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false) else {
            return
    }
    swipeableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    initialCardView.tag = Default.snapshotTag
    cardContentView.updateForRotation()
    cardContentView.superview?.addSubview(initialCardView)
    setupCATrasaction(forInitialView: initialCardView, finalView: cardContentView)
}

//MARK: - Helpers
fileprivate func setupCATrasaction(forInitialView initialView: UIView, finalView: CardContentView) {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(Default.rotationDuration)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { [weak self] in
        self?.cardRotationCompletionHandler(forView: finalView)
    }
    setupInitialCardLayer(initialView.layer)
    setupFinalCardLayer(finalView.layer)
    CATransaction.commit()
}

fileprivate func cardRotationCompletionHandler(forView cardContentView: CardContentView) {
    cardContentView.superview?.subviews.filter { $0.tag == Default.snapshotTag }.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    swipeableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

fileprivate func setupInitialCardLayer(_ startingLayer: CALayer) {
    startingLayer.isDoubleSided = false
    startingLayer.add(scalingAnimation, forKey: "scale")
    startingLayer.add(flipAnimation, forKey: "flipAnimation")
}

fileprivate func setupFinalCardLayer(_ finalLayer: CALayer) {
    finalLayer.isDoubleSided = false
    finalLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(Double.pi), 0, 1, 0)
    finalLayer.add(scalingAnimation, forKey: "scale")
    finalLayer.add(flipAnimation, forKey: "flipAnimation")
}
```

Comment: reset your layer transform to .identity

Comment: @ReinierMelian can you, please, be more specific, when should I reset my layer transform. As I have tried this in completion block and it brakes animation as a result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by discarding all card views and loading them again from scratch after an animation was finished.

Hope this solution will help someone resolving a similar issue.

See code below:

```
fileprivate func cardRotationCompletionHandler(forView cardContentView: CardContentView) {
    cardContentView.superview?.subviews.filter { $0.tag == Default.snapshotTag }.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    swipeableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    refreshCardViews()
}

fileprivate func refreshCardViews() {
    guard !cards.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    //updates relevant models before refresh
    cards.forEach { $0.wasShown = false }
    swipeableView.numberOfActiveView = cards.count > Default.maxNumberOfCards ? Default.maxNumberOfCards : UInt(cards.count)

    //removes all card views from superview
    swipeableView.discardViews()

    //loads all views again
    swipeableView.loadViews()
}
```